# Add language to array[0] if website language is selected, otherwise leave empty

Tags: php, arrays, url, routes, multilingual

I'm using this simple PHP URL router, and I want to implement multiple languages on my website.

I want this to happen the following way

**English Version:**
`www.example.com/en/about-us`

**Norwegian Version:**
`www.example.com/no/about-us`

**Norwegian Version:**
`www.example.com/about-us`

How can I make this work by pushing the array?

Whenever I enter the website I check `$routes[1]` for a string and check if there is a file similar. Like this:

```
if((($routes[1] == "about-us") && ($routes[1] != "about.php")) && (empty($routes[2]))){
    http_response_code(200);
    require 'about_us.php
}
```

The question is, how can I implement so that `$routes[0]` decides the language without creating an offset in the `$routes[]` value?

**This is the routing code I use:**

```
<?php
function getCurrentUri(){
    $basepath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, -1)) . '/';
    $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($basepath));
    if (strstr($uri, '?')) $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
    $uri = '/' . trim($uri, '/');
    return $uri;
}
$base_url = getCurrentUri();
$routes = array();
$routes = explode('/', $base_url);
foreach($routes as $route)
{
    if(trim($route) != '');
}
?>
```

This is what I get from `var_dump()`

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(2) "en" [2]=> string(8) "services" }
```

This is what I need in the ideal situation when language value is selected in the URL

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "en" [1]=> string(8) "services" }
```

And this is what I need when language is not set in the URL

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(8) "services" }
```

Comment: Could you set a default language if a language code is not present in the URL? That way the first array item is guaranteed to be a language instead of needing to worry about checking for an empty string later on.

Comment: Yes, I will require a certain file (database query) if no language code is present, but this would require `array[0]` to be empty. So `array[0]` is pretty much the language array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after ages of testing and failing.

Since I have `$routes[0]` empty all the time I can use `array_splice()` to delete the first element, and re-index the array.

This is what it looks like:

```
if($routes[1] === "en"){
    array_splice($routes,0,1);
}
```